# Mac HDD Firmware for non-Mac-HDDs?

Tags: hard-drive, macbook-pro

First of all: I use a MacBook (white) 13.3" 2Ghz (It says it's a MacBook3,1).

There was an 80GB HDD (Hitachi) built in, which just turned out to be a little too...
Well, it's not enough anymore.
So I cloned the drive with Carbon Copy Cloner (can recommend it by the way) to a 250GB FUJITSU MHY2250BH.

Now it has been my understanding that I need a special Mac Firmware for the drive to use certain features, for example the HDD temp display the iStat dashboard widget usually gives me. Google couldn't come up with anything useful so far, so here's what the question actually is about:
Can I get the drive to be "fully functional", e.g. with some Firmware upgrade or something else?

If I am completely wrong with any of my assumptions – pointing that out would be an acceptable answer, too.

EDIT: Just to specify: The HDD itself works, but there are some minor inconveniences left:
The system boots slowlyer and iStatPro can't display the HDD's temp.

Comment: I confirm that Apple sets on iMac hard drives its own firmware to check disk's temperature without relying on SMART technology, to adjust fan rotation speed. On the MacBook aluminium unibody, the temperature check is made by a probe externally to the drive. So this problem does not exist for this MacBook family. But I think the MacBook white (yours) is like the imac. I didn't have found a solution yet. If you replace the drive by an ssd you will no longer worry about the temperature of your drive and the performances will be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a special OSX firmware to use a different internal disk. Just plug it in and all will work.

Comment: Yep, I know. It works and boots and whatnot, problem is: it boots just a little slower and iStatPro can't read the temperatur information from the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it boots slower, is it noticeably so?  My guess might be a slower speed HDD or maybe just from accumulated cruft that you haven't noticed until switching drives?  After using CCC your HDD is good to go, doesn't require anything else.